# KLExpandingSelect works on first load, not after another view has been presented and dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c

Been stuck on this for a while, would really appreciated your help!

I am using https://github.com/KieranLafferty/KLExpandingSelect, and I have implemented it, all works when I load initially, I then assign one of the 'petals' on tap to present a view controller:

```
 [self presentViewController:nextViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I then have a close button, which dismisses the view like so:

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

And when I return to the initial view, when I hold down to visit another view, the menu doesn't show and nothing happens!

Please help, cheers!

Comment: Sorted it! I found a rogue storyboard segue, deleted that and all sorted.

Comment: Ryan, you should post an answer to your question and then accept it, so people know the problem is resolved. That also makes it easier for others to find the solution if they search for it.